# How to find radius of circle given its center and the equation to an ellipse

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Question: A circle is drawn with its center at (8,0) and with radius r such that the circle cuts the ellipse $x^2 + 4y^2 = 16$ at right angles. Find the radius of the circle.

I understand that the tangent of a circle at the point they intersect is the normal of the ellipse. I don't where to go from there to get the radius. Thank you

Comment: Please use MathJax syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle and ellipse equations:
$$(x-8)^2+y^2=r^2; \frac{x^2}{4^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2}=1.$$
The slopes of their tangents at the common intersection point $x_0$:
$$2(x-8)+2y\cdot y'=0 \Rightarrow y'(x_0)=-\frac{x_0-8}{y(x_0)},$$
$$\frac{2x}{4^2}+\frac{2yy'}{2^2}=0 \Rightarrow y'(x_0)=-\frac{x_0}{4y(x_0)}.$$
For the tangent lines to be perpendicular the product of slopes must be $-1$:
$$(x_0-8)x_0=-4y^2(x_0) \Rightarrow x_0=2.$$
Now from the ellipse equation we will find $y_0^2$:
$$y_0^2=3.$$
Finally from the circle equation we will find the radius:
$$r^2=(2-8)^2+3=39 \Rightarrow r=\sqrt{39}.$$

Comment: How did you know X0=2?

Comment: Using ellipse equation: $(x_0-8)x_0=-4(4-\frac{x_0^2}{4}) \Rightarrow x_0=2$.

Comment: What did you do to get rid of the 4y^2 to get x_0 =2?

Comment: Oh wait I think I get it. I'm assuming you substituted 0 for x_0 on BOTH sides of the equation.

Comment: Note from ellipse equation $y^2(x_0)=y_0^2=4-\frac{x_0^2}{4}$. So $y(x_0)$ is not $y$ multiplied by $(x_0)$, but the value of $y$ in the ellipse equation at $x_0$.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand how you get to the ellipse equation now.

Comment: The $y^2(x_0)=y_0^2=4-\frac{x_0^2}{4}$ bit

Comment: Ellipse equation: $\frac{x^2}{4^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2}=1$ or $y^2=4-\frac{x^2}{4}$. Plug $x=x_0$ to find $y_0^2=y^(x_0)$. This is how: $y^2(x_0)= y_0^2=4-\frac{x_0^2}{4}.$

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the circle is
$$(x-8)^2+y^2=R^2\leftrightarrow x^2+y^2-16x=R^2-64.$$
The equations of the tangent lines of these two conics at an intersection point $(x_0,y_0)$ are respectively (see [here](http://planetmath.org/tangentofconicsection))
$$x_0x+4y_0 y=16\quad\mbox{and}\quad x_0x+y_0 y-8(x+x_0)=R^2-64.$$
These two lines are orthogonal iff the following scalar product is zero
$$0=(x_0,4y_0)\cdot (x_0-8,y_0)=x_0^2+4y_0^2-8x_0=16-8x_0\implies x_0=2.$$
Hence $y_0^2=(16-x_0^2)/4=3$ and
$$R=\sqrt{(x_0-8)^2+y_0^2}=\sqrt{39}.$$

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the equations of the tangents of the conics. How did you get " 2x0x+8y0y=16 "

Comment: @Jo Villar See the link I gave you: http://planetmath.org/tangentofconicsection

Comment: How would you solve this using implicit differentiation. I'm sure it takes longer but  i would also like to know doing it that way.

Comment: By implicit differentiation $2x x' + 8y y' = 0$ therefore $dy/dx=-x_0/(4y_0)$ is the angular coefficient of the tangent. Compare this with $x_0x+4y_0 y=16$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1** The straight line from $(8, 0)$ to the intersection point must be tangent to the ellipse. Using $y^\prime = 2 y$, this property remains true in the $(x, y^\prime)$ plane, where the ellipse is now a circle.

**Hint 2** The ellipse can be parametrized by $(x, y) = (4 \cos(t), 2 \sin(t))$. Find the values of $t$ where the tangent vector is proportional to $(x-8, y)$.